# Boost named_semaphore ownerwship in shared library

Tags: c++, boost

I have a shared library where I created some functionality with semaphores. I am using `boost::interprocess::named_semaphore` with a thin wrapper around it. This library I am now linking dynamically with a small program.

The problem I am experiencing is that the semaphores are not deleted after I run my application. This problem only happens on Windows, on Linux the semaphores do get deleted. Now, **I am** calling `boost::interprocess::named_semaphore::remove` in the destructor of the wrapper I mentioned because the `named_semaphore` does not do that itself.

Also, if I call `boost::interprocess::named_semaphore::remove` directly in my application and not inside the library code the semaphore **does** get deleted! Strange!

Any ideas of what could be going wrong?

Comment: Probably destructor is not called, Try putting a print statement in destructor

Comment: Thanks @balki. That's not the case, I've already been through that.